# Possible issue with environment / authentication - BigQuery Admin: {invalid_grant, Invalid JWT Signature}

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to access BigQuery API for the first time using Python and am following the tutorial guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets). My ultimate goal is to create datasets, but I seem to be having trouble with basic public data access.

I've created a service account with the following:

BigQuery Admin 
BigQuery Data Owner

Using this service account, I generated a private key (.json) and kept it nicely tucked away on my local machine, and am referencing it in my `gcp_key_path` file path.

However, I run into the following jwt issue when running the lines below. I saw a GitHub issue on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8736#event-2510884623 suggesting that the jwt token expiration may be an issue. I'm not sure how to check for this nor if this is automatically set when using a service account to make this request. I checked my sys time (Mac OS Catalina v10.15.6) and nothing seems to be obviously off.

If someone has run into this before, would greatly appreciate a layman's explanation on what is going on, and guidance (or pointer to docs) that can help me learn how to fix this issue.

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_id = "[project_name].[file_name]"
file_path = '/path/to/my/data_file.json'
gcp_key_path = '/path/to/my/service/account/private/key.json'

# set the environment variable explicitly
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = gcp_key_path

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(gcp_key_path)
dataset_ref = client.dataset("hacker_news", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)
```

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 674, in get_dataset
            timeout=timeout,
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 637, in _call_api
            return call()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
            on_error=on_error,
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
            return target()
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 431, in api_request
            timeout=timeout,
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 289, in _make_request
            method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 327, in _do_request
            url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 460, in request
            self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
            self.refresh(request)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 361, in refresh
            access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(request, self._token_uri, assertion)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 153, in jwt_grant
            response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 124, in _token_endpoint_request
            _handle_error_response(response_body)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 60, in _handle_error_response
            raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
        google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}')
```

Pasting in the output of my pip freeze in case libraries may be outdated

```
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.3
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
google-api-core==1.22.4
google-api-python-client==1.9.3
google-auth==1.22.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-bigquery==2.1.0
google-cloud-core==1.4.3
google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
grpcio==1.32.0
httplib2==0.18.1
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
proto-plus==1.10.1
protobuf==3.12.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
rsa==4.6
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Comment: 1) The problem is not caused by an invalid JWT Signature. The Google Client will refresh the Access Token before it expires which validates the token. 2) Your problem is most likely out of date library versions. Edit your question and include the results of `pip freeze`. 3) I recommend that you use `virtualenv` so that you do not have multiple projects using conflicting libraries.

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of the CLI installed: `gcloud components update`.

Comment: Thanks John, I ran the gcloud components update and printed out the pip freeze output. I re-ran the script, and I still keep getting the same error. For (1), how do I know if this is working properly? Also what makes you believe that (2) is the culprit here? Appreciate the help.

Comment: The Python libraries are either current or very recent. Create an environment and then just `pip install google-cloud-bigquery`. The required dependencies should be installed.

Comment: I believe it is a library version/collision problem because of years working with the libraries. I also ran you code and it works on my system (Windows 10). This means an environment problem on your side.

Comment: Hm, that's useful to know that it is an environment problem. Any tips on where/what to start checking? Also, I made an isolated virtual environment and installed the required dependencies. Ran into the same problem, so I think we can eliminate the library version collision here?

Comment: Create a new service account and JSON key file and try that. Maybe there is a problem with the service account.

Comment: Thanks John for your persistent help. It was my own mistake as you've guessed on the setup. I didn't enable the BigQuery API. After enabling the API, the script seems to have worked!

Answer (score 2):

Found my dumb error. I forgot to enable the BigQuery API service... Step (2) in the quickstart [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-web-ui?_ga=2.252226570.-2005596882.1587006568&_gac=1.18548299.1601272912.CjwKCAjw8MD7BRArEiwAGZsrBbyZK9WrBivPQTmYk3x4zZiGdOxLLhZONNqf6MJEyPQalUE5cvD2DxoCD_cQAvD_BwE)